# Having trouble running public HashMap method

Tags: java, hashmap

The purpose and goal of the method is to print the hash map in reverse from `<Key, Value>` to `<Value, Key>`. But I'm having a problem on line 7(**revrse();**) where where I get the error

> "*The method reverse(Map<Integer,String>) in the type lab8_Part3 is not applicable for the arguments ()*".

All the solutions eclipse suggest result in an error and I'm stumped. Help is appreciated

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverse();
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> reverse(Map<Integer, String> map) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> reversed = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        reversed.put("Eightenn", 18);
        reversed.put("Fifty", 50);
        reversed.put("neThreeTwo", 132);
        reversed.put("Ocho", 8);
        reversed.put("Forty-one", 41);
        System.out.println("Reversered map " + reversed);
        for(int key : map.keySet()) {
            String value = map.get(key);

            if(!reversed.containsKey(value)) {
                reversed.put(value, key);
            }
        }
        return reversed;
    }
}
```

The purpose and goal of the method is to print the hash map in reverse from `<Key, Value>` to `<Value, Key>`.

Comment: When the code reaches the line `HashMap<String, Integer> reversed = new HashMap<String, Integer>()`, what do you expect to be in the variable named `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reverse()` method expects `Map<Integer, String>` parameter and return a `Map<Integer, String>` object, but you're calling it without any arguments and without assigning the object.

I modified your code, this should work.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> original = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        original.put(18, "Eightenn");
        original.put(50, "Fifty");
        original.put(132, "neThreeTwo");

        Map<String, Integer> reversed = reverse(original);
        System.out.println("Reversed map: " + reversed);
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> reverse(Map<Integer, String> map) {
        Map<String, Integer> reversed = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int key : map.keySet()) {
            String value = map.get(key);
            reversed.put(value, key);
        }
        return reversed;
    }
}
```